# Copy formula from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I'm currently trying to write a Programm to migrate a lot of Excel files to another Directory. For this usecase I pieced together the following code snippets. Search for all links inside an Excel file and write it into another worksheet in this file.

```
Sub LinkCheck_detail()

Dim aLinks           As Variant
Dim i                As Integer
Dim ws               As Worksheet
Dim anyWS            As Worksheet
Dim anyCell          As Range
Dim reportWS         As Worksheet
Dim nextReportRow    As Long
Dim shtName          As String
Dim bWsExists        As Boolean


shtName = "Verknuepfungen_detail"

'Löscht Datenblatt falls es bereits exisitiert.
Sheets("Verknuepfungen_detail").Delete

' Sheet mit den Verknuepfungen anlegen
For Each ws In Application.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = shtName Then bWsExists = True
Next ws

If bWsExists = False Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
    ws.Name = shtName
    ws.Select
    ws.Move After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

    ' Komplettes Workbook analysieren auf Verknuepfungen
Set reportWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtName)
    reportWS.Cells.Clear
    reportWS.Range("A1") = "Sheet"
    reportWS.Range("B1") = "Zelle"
    reportWS.Range("C1") = "Formel"
    reportWS.Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True

    aLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then

        ' Wenn Verknuepfungen gefunden dann diese in Ergebnis schreiben
        For Each anyWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If anyWS.Name <> reportWS.Name Then
                For Each anyCell In anyWS.UsedRange
                    If anyCell.HasFormula Then
                        If InStr(anyCell.formula, "[") > 0 Then
                            nextReportRow = reportWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            reportWS.Range("A" & nextReportRow) = anyWS.Name
                            reportWS.Range("B" & nextReportRow) = anyCell.Address
                            reportWS.Range("C" & nextReportRow) = "'" & anyCell.formula
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Keine Verknüpfungen gefunden in der Datei."
    End If

    reportWS.Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ' Zuruecksetzen der Hilfs-Variablen
    Set reportWS = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then do the changes to the path.

```
Sub ReplaceEPP4_detail()
' Author Tobias Fandrich
' Finden von String "oldPath" in Dateipfaden und die Ersetzung durch "newPath"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim linkList As Range
Dim linkCell As Range


Set ws = ActiveSheet

' Alle Eintraege selektieren
ws.Range("c1", ActiveSheet.Range("c1").End(xlDown)).Select

' Selektion zu Variable
Set linkList = Selection

' EPP4 entfernen und gegen EZE ersetzen
linkList.Replace "oldPath", "newPath", xlPart

End Sub
```

So this leaves my with a new sheet that has the following columns:
Sheet, Cell, Formula

And now I Need to write this back to the Sheets where I got it from.

```
Sub UpdateLinksFormula()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetWS As String
    Dim sourceWS As String

    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As String
    Dim newFormula As String
    Dim i As Integer ' Variable fuer Sheets Count
    Dim rowCount As Integer ' Variable fuer Rows Count
    Dim j As Integer ' Variable fuer Schleife
    Dim bWsExists As Boolean

    sourceWS = "Verknuepfungen_detail"

    ' Auf Arbeitsblatt mit Verknuepfungen springen
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name = sourceWS Then
        bWsExists = True: Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    If bWsExists Then
        Sheets(sourceWS).Select
    Else
        Beep
        MsgBox "Verknuepfungen_detail nicht gefunden!"
    End If

    ' Groesse bestimmen
    rowCount = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    ' Debug.Print (j)

    ' Schleife zum schreiben der aktualisierten Links
    For j = 2 To rowCount
        targetWS = Cells(j, 1)
        targetCell = Cells(j, 2)
        newFormula = Cells(j, 3)

        Debug.Print (targetWS)
        Debug.Print (targetCell)
        Debug.Print (newFormula)

        ' Pseudocode
        ' Sheets(targetWS)!.Cell(targetCell).formula = newFormula

        Sheets("targetWS").Range("targetCell").formula = newFormula

    Next j

End Sub
```

The Thing is it just won't work and I tried it with "", without etc. but it seems it just won't do it.

The second Problem I'm running into is on how to automate this Thing so that I doesn't update just one Excel file but hundreds of it.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it giving an error? if so where?

Comment: Sheets("targetWS").Range("targetCell").formula = newFormula

There I get an index out of bounds error.

Comment: Why not simply using `Workbook.ChangeLink` method?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836537.aspx

Comment: I will give it a try and see if it works.

Does that Change the links in the Name Manager and the VBA code too?

And it Shows Excel 2013, we use 2010 here.

Comment: It does the same as Data tab - Connections group - Edit Links - Change Source.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-or-change-source-workbooks-of-external-references-links-ae3e687c-97ae-4d9b-b684-8756a5301253#bmchange_the_source_workbook_for_all_ex

Comment: That Looks quite nice. Do you have any code snippet where it Loops over all the links in a workbook?

Answer (score 0):

`Sheets(targetWS).Range(targetCell).formula = newFormula`

try this.

Comment: Is it possible to explain where this fits in, rather than saying "Here, try this..."?

Comment: It was under the Pseudo Code comment and worked. But I'm currently trying the Version with the ChangeLink function as that would be a much better Performance.